# overwrite a line of text inside a text file that begins with a string in python

Tags: python-3.x

I have a text file as follows:

myfile.txt

```
[items]
colors = red, purple, orange, blue
[eat]
food = burgers, pizza, hotdogs 
[furry]
animals = birds, dogs, cats
```

I have a dictionary:

```
my_dict = {'colors':'green, black','animals':'donkey, tigers'}
```

I want to open the file *myfile.txt* and search for the keys inside the file and replace the lines with the values of my_dict so that myfile.txt should look like:

myfile.txt

```
[items]
colors = green, black
[eat]
food = burgers, pizza, hotdogs 
[furry]
animals = donkey, tigers
```

I've tried doing something like:

```
def func(my_dict):
   # Read in the file
   with open('myfile.txt', 'r') as file :
       filedata = file.read()

       # Replace the target string
       filedata = filedata.replace('colors', my_dict)

   # Write the file out again
   with open('myfile.txt', 'w') as file:
       file.write(filedata)
```

The problem is that I get an output like:

```
myfile.txt
green, black = red, purple, orange, blue
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

New version preserving text that doesn't have an equals sign

```
my_dict = {'colors': 'green, black', 'animals': 'donkey, tigers'}

def func(my_dict):
    # Get the file contents like you were already doing
    with open('myfile.txt', 'r') as file:
        filedata = file.read()


    # Now split the rows on newline
    lines = filedata.split('\n')
    # create a new list
    new_lines = []
    # Process each line of the file's contents
    for line in lines:
        # If it doesn't have an '=', just add it and continue iteration
        if "=" not in line: 
            new_lines.append(line)
            continue

        key, value = line.split("=")

        # if the key is in replacement dictionary, append a line with the new value
        if key.strip() in my_dict.keys():
            new_lines.append(f'{key.strip()} = {my_dict[key.strip()]}')
        # else just add the old line
        else:
            new_lines.append(line)

    with open('myfile.txt', 'w') as file:
        # join the new lines for the file with a newline character
        file.write('\n'.join(new_lines))

func(my_dict)
```

Old version

```
# Get the file contents like you were already doing
with open('myfile.txt', 'r') as file:
    filedata = file.read()

# Now split the rows on newline
lines = filedata.split('\n')
# Create an empty dictionary
pairs = {}
# Process each line of the file's contents
for line in lines:
    # If it doesn't have an '=', skip the line
    if "=" not in line: continue
    key, value = line.split("=")
    # fill the dictionary with the keys and values in the file
    pairs[key.strip()] = value.strip()

my_dict = {'colors': 'green, black', 'animals': 'donkey, tigers'}

# replace the previous files values with any new values from the new dictionary
for k, v in my_dict.items():
    pairs[k] = v

# format the dictionary back into a line of text "colors = blue, black, etc."
new_lines = [f'{k} = {v}' for k, v in pairs.items()]

with open('myfile.txt', 'w') as file:
    # join the new lines for the file with a newline character
    file.write('\n'.join(new_lines))
```

Comment: There is other text in the file that does not have the '=' that I need to keep in the file.  With this code it is deleting everything and only keeping strings that have '='.  What to do so that it doesn't delete the other text?

Comment: Ahh, I see, well then something like this should work better - I will edit my answer

Answer (score 0):

You have given a function that takes as my_dict but you used as a string in replace method. You should have given how you called function. However, this is the solution. Comments explains what happenings. Instead of reading from file, I just created a string same as your file content. You can just change that related part.
We used split method to have as key and value pairs.

```
my_dict = {'colors':'green, black','animals':'donkey, tigers'}


def func(my_dict):
    filedata = """colors = red, purple, orange, blue\nfood = burgers, pizza, hotdogs \nanimals = birds, dogs, cats"""
    #get lines of line
    lines = filedata.split("\n")
    #this will store our final text
    fileDict = {}
    for line in lines:
        #get key from file/source
        key = line.split(" = ")[0]
        if(key in my_dict.keys()):
            #if key exist in your dict, change it with your my_dict value
            newValues = my_dict[key]
            fileDict[key] = newValues
        else:
            #if key not exist in your my_dict, use file/source values
            fileDict[key] = line.split(" =")[1]

    #stringify dictionary
    text = ""
    for key,value in fileDict.items():
        text += f"{key} = {value}\n" 

    #write to file
    with open('myfile.txt', 'w') as file:
       file.write(filedata)  

func(my_dict)
```

Answer (score -1):

You need to split the sentence (line) on the equal sign and replace the second part of the equal sign. This can expand to your other data as well

```
with open("myfile.txt") as file:
    for line in file.readlines():
        if "colors" in line:
            filedata = line.replace(line.split(" = ")[1], my_dict["colors"])
```

When you write, the syntax should be the same.